# Scale view on tablet to look similar to phone

Tags: android

I created a simple Android app. It only has one activity and one view.

The app was designed for phones. I used the "device independent pixel" unit (dp) for all of my UI element measurements, and RelativeLayout for most of my layouts. The app looks good on a small screen.

On a large screen (such as a tablet), all the elements are tiny, spread apart, and there is a large empty space at the bottom. It's true that the physical size of the UI elements is roughly the same between the tablet and the phone, which is what the dp unit promises, but it's not really what I want for this app. I'd like the whole interface to just get bigger and fill the screen as much as possible, like when you run an iPhone app on an iPad and push the "2x" button.

What's the best way to do this? Do I have to write separate views for each screen size? Should I use pixels (px) instead of dp?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using px as a measurement would actually be worse - as new tablets have high DPI screens, meaning 100px is going to be visually smaller on a tablet than it would on a mid spec phone.

Your best option is to use layout overrides (layout-sw600dp, layout-sw700dp). **Although simply enlarging a phone layout is strictly discouraged**.. if you want to take the shortcut all you have to do is copy your phone layout into the sw* folders and tweak all the dp measurements.

You will also need to force the tablet into portrait mode using:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: The problem I find is with the tweaking of dp measurement. Is there no way that Android can automatically detect how big the screen and multiple the dp values by that factor? Imageviews are worse when they wrapcontent too